# .NET Naming Convention for Namespaces

Tags: .net, namespaces, naming-conventions

I understand basic naming conventions and capitalization conventions in .NET, and have read .NET's naming guidelines [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx), but there's one thing in particular that I'm unsure over.

My company name is, for example, XYZ Studios.  We have created a new system, again for example, called a Large Object Management System and we are calling it LOMS for short.

I want to create a .NET project to contain the entity framework entities which map to the LOMS database.  The namespace name will be XYZStudios.LOMS.Entities.

My question is, which of the following is the correct capitilization for the namespace? :

- XYZStudios.LOMS.Entities ?
- XyzStudio.Loms.Entities ?
- XYZStudio.Loms.Entities ?

Comment: All of them. This is a opinion based decision of the developer.

Comment: As Scott says, this is up to you. If you want to follow Microsoft's lead, I think you would go with XyzStudio.Loms.Entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would lean towards your second bullet of :

```
XyzStudio.Loms.Entities
```

The points of contention here are LOMS and XYZStudio, so we can disregard talking about the entities portion.

For LOMS being referred to as `Loms` in the namespace follows the precedence of other acronyms in use in .Net code. Examples:

```
System.Xml
System.Json
Newtonsoft.Json
```

For XYZStudio being reffered to as `XyzStudio`, some precedent exists (and there is probably more):

Sony Computer Entertainment (SCE) is referred to as `Sce` in their [ATF namespace](https://github.com/SonyWWS/ATF/blob/master/Framework/Atf.Atgi/Anim.cs).

```
namespace Sce.Atf.Atgi
```

Also, if you look at java guidelines for namespaces, they don't capitalize anything, regardless of being a proper noun or not.